# $('form').validate is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, wizard

I am trying to implement a wizard in MVC using the techniques described in the article [Create a Wizard in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://afana.me/post/create-wizard-in-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx). (I'm using the latest version of MVC.)

But I seem to be having trouble with the following line of code:

```
var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
```

This line causes an error because `$("form").validate` is undefined.

Unfortunately, I don't really know how this particular code is intended to work, and so I'm not sure how to fix it. Can someone explain what is happening here? Where is `validate` supposed to be defined?

Comment: It's supposed to be defined in the jQuery validate plugin, which you probably included somewhere ?

Comment: I wondered about that. But my layout file includes `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css") @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`.

Comment: Try console.log($("form")) so you can check in the console if the form is actually in the DOM, and if you can find validate as a method under the jquery object's prototype (`__proto__`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually by default the _Layout.cshtml file includes script files right at the end of the page (just before the closing body tag) and if you look at the rendered page in the browser, you would see that.

The content from regular views is embedded where you have @RenderBody call in the layout file. As you can see that the call to RenderBody comes before the included scripts. That is why any javascript code you write that refers to external code will not work.

The "Scripts" section is defined in the layout file even after the included scripts. So if you use @section "Scripts", the arbitrary code that you put there is guaranteed to come after the included js files and hence it will work.

Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Yes, this is the issue. I actually figured it out last night after some research and head scratching. (BTW, it is not necessary to address my name @JonathanWood in an answer.) Thanks.

Comment: I started writing a comment before realizing it will be too long hence converted that to an answer. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you didn't include jquery validate as a script in your html file. Did you do:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Or include it locally?

Comment: I don't have exactly that line, but I have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` at the top of my layout file.

Comment: It could be that the path to your jqueryval is incorrect, can you double check that?

Comment: My rendered markup includes `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>`, and I can click the link from the browser and the script file comes up as expected.

Comment: @JonathanWood - then the file is there, and it's strange that the function wouldn't be defined. Are you sure the plugin is included before the script in your question etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically are you referring to here by *plugin*?

Comment: are there more than one `<form>` tag??

Comment: No, but I think I solved this. In the Login view that Visual Studio created for me automatically, it has `@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }` at the bottom of the cshtml file. This also works on my new page--I had it at the top of the page. So order matters. Perhaps it must come after the modernizr scripts??

Comment: @JonathanWood It extends the jquery object `$` with its own methods, so it must be added after the jquery library has been loaded. Also, you cannot use the plugin in your own script, if the plugin hasn't been loaded.

Comment: It was after the jquery include. I see that the order matters, but still a bit fuzzy about which files were causing the problem.

Comment: Also note that in order to activate the plugin, the DOM has to be fully loaded. Either this can be achieved by wrapping your script into a `$(document).ready(function(){});` or by including your script at the bottom of the body (after all html has been loaded first).